# Remove JSESSIONID cookie from Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I have a stateless Spring application, so I have no use for sessions. I would like to disable everything that has to do with sessions. I have a context.xml Tomcat config, where I have added this:

```
<Manager pathname="" />
```

Source^: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/manager.html

I have also added this to every http block in my spring security xml file:

```
create-session="stateless" disable-url-rewriting="true"
```

Even with these things done, if I manually delete my JSESSIONID cookie, any page I hit will add it again. How do I prevent this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11327682/106261

Comment: the duplicate is NOT a duplicate

Comment: any idea how to do this with spring boot and embedded tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tomcat configuration, you can try adding the following attributes to your Context element

```
<Context cookies=false disableURLRewriting=true ...
```

From [tomcat 6 doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html)

Answer (score 1):

JSPs create a session by default, so that is the [most likely cause](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-unwanted-session-creation).

Use

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

to prevent session creation.

If you also add

```
<debug />
```

to the top of your Spring Security configuration, it will log new session creations, along with a stack dump, so you can work out where they are taking place.

The debug filter this adds to the filter chain is a useful feature for tracking how requests are handled during development, not just for session creation issues.